# Cómo evitar que se muestren fechas mayores a la fecha actual con DatePickerDialog

Tags: android-studio, datepicker

tengo un DtePickerDialog el cual esta en un registro el problema es que necesito que no se muestren fechas mayores a la actual por ejemplo la ultima fecha que quiero que se muestre seria la del 20 /05/2021 que seria la actual pero no logro hacerlo ya que por alguna razón me muestra hasta el año 2100 a continuacion dejo el codigo que tengo hasta el momento.

En primer lugar declaro el texview donde muestro la fecha y el datepickerDialog para poder usar la libreria

```
private TextView mDisplayDate;
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;
```

Luego le pongo una propiedad onClickListener para que al usuario se le despliege el dialogo con la fecha

```
mDisplayDate = findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(v -> {

}
```

Como siguiente paso realizo la lógica para que la fecha se muestre de forma "correcta" pero hasta el momento no se donde puedo asignar para que se muestre la fecha actual debido a que lo hice siguiendo un tutorial.

```
mDisplayDate = findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    mDisplayDate.setOnClickListener(v -> {
  
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                RegistroUsuario.this,
                android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                mDateSetListener,
                year, month, day);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();       

}
```

Por ultimo al DatePickerDialog le asigno las propiedades correspondientes para el llamado del metodo

```
mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        private static final String TAG = "";

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month + 1;

            Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: d/MMMM/yyyy: " + day + month  + year);

            String date  = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

            mDisplayDate.setText(date);
        }
```

Y eso seria todo lo que tengo hasta el momento si alguien me puede instruir le agradeceria mucho, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: no te olvides de agregar la etiqueta del lenguaje de programación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solo debes asignar los limites a sus respectivos atributos `MaxDate` para el maximo y `MinDate` para el minimo

en tu caso solo el `MaxDate`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(...);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Excelente esto ha funcionado muy bien, muchas gracias!